# How to inspect the value inside a product (Σ)?

Tags: agda

I am trying to wrap my head around the `Σ` type by playing with a `filterVec` function, analogous to the `filter` function available for lists. See my implementation below:

```
-- Some imports we will need later
open import Data.Bool
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Product
open import Data.Vec

-- The filterVec function
filterVec : {n : ℕ} -> (ℕ -> Bool) -> Vec ℕ n -> Σ ℕ (λ length → Vec ℕ length)
filterVec _ [] = 0 , []
filterVec f (x ∷ xs) with filterVec f xs
... | length , filtered = if f x then (suc length , x ∷ filtered) else (length , filtered)
```

Happy with my function, I decided to test it

```
dummyVec : Vec ℕ 5
dummyVec = 1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ 4 ∷ 5 ∷ []

dummyFn : Vec ℕ 5
dummyFn with filterVec (λ _ → true) dummyVec
dummyFn | length , xs = {!!} -- I would like to return xs here, but Agda throws a type error
```

For some reason, Agda is unable to tell that `length` is `5`, so it doesn't allow me to return `xs`. However, the code below does work:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
dummyProof : proj₁ (filterVec (λ _ → true) dummyVec) ≡ 5
dummyProof = refl
```

I am utterly confused by this behavior. In the case of `dummyFn`, Agda cannot tell that the length is 5, but in the case of `dummyProof`, Agda proves it without any problem.

What am I missing? How can I get `dummyFn` to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`with` binds a value to a name. If you want to compute, you can use `let`:

```
dummyFn′ : Vec ℕ 5
dummyFn′ = let length , xs = filterVec (λ _ → true) dummyVec
           in xs
```

Let's look at the following example:

```
dummy : Set
dummy with 5
dummy | x = {!!}
```

Should the `x` magically reduce to `5` in the hole? No. You've given `5` another name — `x`, and those expressions are neither judgementally nor propositionally equal.

Now in your example:

```
dummyFn : Vec ℕ 5
dummyFn with filterVec (λ _ → true) dummyVec
dummyFn | length , xs = {!!}
```

You've given the `length` name to the length of `xs`. And it does not reduce to `5`. It's a name. If you want both to give a name and to remember what the name is for, there is the [`inspect`](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Relation/Binary/PropositionalEquality.agda#L156) idiom for this:

```
dummyFn′′ : Vec ℕ 5
dummyFn′′ with filterVec (λ _ → true) dummyVec | inspect (filterVec (λ _ → true)) dummyVec
dummyFn′′ | length , xs | [ refl ] = xs
```